# How can I run an RDP file with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, scripting, remote-desktop, rdp

So far I have:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""C:\Server01.rdp""")
```

But when I run it, nothing happens. Is it even possible to run an RDP file with VBScript? If so, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got it to work everyone:

 objShell.Run "mstsc.exe server01.rdp"

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

try calling mstsc.exe with the .rdp file name passed in:

```
objShell.Run(""mstsc C:\server01.rdp"")
```

Comment: No, I get "The system cannot find the specified file".

Comment: you'll need to make sure that your environment path variables point correctly (if you can do start-> run -> mstsc c:\server01.rdp then you should be ok on this). Also check the quotation marks on my answer - I didn't include the extra one that you originally had!

Comment: As a side thought, you could use a batch file instead of VBScript if you want, since this is a relatively simple operation.

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid connection file" when trying to run it. Why's that? I'm sure the path is correct.

Comment: Could I run the batch file using a VBScript?

Comment: so the file C:\Server01.rdp exists, and you can run it manually using the start -> run method described above? If so, then the vbscript you posted should work. To address your second comment, you can create a batch file by opening notepad and typing: mstsc C:\server01.rdp, then saving the file as myBatch.bat

Comment: Got it! objShell.Run "mstsc.exe server01.rdp" Thanks for the help!

Comment: You answer is not valid VBS. You need three quotes. `objShell.Run("""mstsc C:\server01.rdp""")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run mstsc.exe and pass the rdp file in as an argument.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice with VBScript, could you explain in more detail, perhaps with some code.

Comment: That link refers to the command line, how can I do that with a script?

Answer (score 0):

This will work: (In PHP with VBSCRIPT):

```
<script type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript">
<!--
const L_FullScreenWarn1_Text = "Your current security settings do not allow automatically switching to fullscreen mode."
const L_FullScreenWarn2_Text = "You can use ctrl-alt-pause to toggle your remote desktop session to fullscreen mode"
const L_FullScreenTitle_Text = "Remote Desktop Web Connection "
const L_ErrMsg_Text         = "Error connecting to remote computer: "
const L_ClientNotSupportedWarning_Text = "Remote Desktop 6.0 does not support CredSSP over TSWeb."
const L_RemoteDesktopCaption_ErrorMessage =  "Remote Desktop Connection"
const L_InvalidServerName_ErrorMessage = "An invalid server name was specified."

sub window_onload()
   if not autoConnect() then
       msgbox("VB")
   end if
end sub

function autoConnect()

    Dim sServer
    Dim iFS, iAutoConnect

    sServer = getQS ("Server")
    iAutoConnect = getQS ("AutoConnect")
    iFS = getQS ("FS")

    if NOT IsNumeric ( iFS ) then
        iFS = 0
    else
        iFS = CInt ( iFS )
    end if

    if iAutoConnect <> 1 then
        autoConnect = false
        exit function
    else


        if IsNull ( sServer ) or sServer = "" then
            sServer = window.location.hostname
        end if

        btnConnect ()
        autoConnect = true
    end if

end function

function getQS ( sKey )
    Dim iKeyPos, iDelimPos, iEndPos
    Dim sURL, sRetVal
    iKeyPos = iDelimPos = iEndPos = 0
    sURL = window.location.href

    if sKey = "" Or Len(sKey) &lt; 1 then
        getQS = ""
        exit function
    end if

    iKeyPos = InStr ( 1, sURL, sKey )

    if iKeyPos = 0 then
        sRetVal = ""
        exit function
    end if

    iDelimPos = InStr ( iKeyPos, sURL, "=" )
    iEndPos = InStr ( iDelimPos, sURL, "&" )

    if iEndPos = 0 then
        sRetVal = Mid ( sURL, iDelimPos + 1 )
    else
        sRetVal = Mid ( sURL, iDelimPos + 1, iEndPos - iDelimPos - 1 )
    end if

    getQS = sRetVal
end function


sub OnControlLoadError
    Msgbox("You wont be able to connect trough Remote Desktop")
end sub

sub OnControlLoad
   set Control = Document.getElementById("MsRdpClient")
   if Not Control is Nothing then
      if Control.readyState = 4 then
        BtnConnect()
      else
          Msgbox("You wont be able to connect trough Remote Desktop")
      end if
   else 
       Msgbox("You wont be able to connect trough Remote Desktop")
   end if
end sub


sub BtnConnect
Dim serverName

serverName = "<?=$_POST["RDserver"]?>"
serverName = trim(serverName)

On Error Resume Next
MsRdpClient.server = serverName
If Err then
msgbox
L_InvalidServerName_ErrorMessage,0,L_RemoteDesktopCaption_ErrorMessage
Err.Clear
exit sub
end if
On Error Goto 0

Dim ClientUserName
ClientUserName = "<?=trim($_POST["RDuser"])?>"
MsRdpClient.UserName = ClientUserName
MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings.ClearTextPassword = "<?=trim($_POST["RDpass"])?>"
MsRdpClient.FullScreen = TRUE
resWidth = screen.width
resHeight = screen.height
MsRdpClient.DesktopWidth = resWidth
MsRdpClient.DesktopHeight = resHeight
MsRdpClient.Width = resWidth
MsRdpClient.Height = resHeight
MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectDrives = FALSE
MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectPrinters = FALSE
MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectPorts = FALSE
MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectSmartCards = FALSE
MsRdpClient.FullScreenTitle = L_FullScreenTitle_Text & "-" & serverName & "-"
MsRdpClient.Connect
end sub

-->
    </script>
    <object id="MsRdpClient" language="vbscript" onreadystatechange="OnControlLoad" onerror="OnControlLoadError"  classid="CLSID:4eb89ff4-7f78-4a0f-8b8d-2bf02e94e4b2" width="800" height="600"></object>

<script language="VBScript">
<!--
sub ReturnToConnectPage()
me.close
end sub

sub MsRdpClient_OnConnected()

end sub

sub MsRdpClient_OnDisconnected(disconnectCode)
   extendedDiscReason = MsRdpClient.ExtendedDisconnectReason
   majorDiscReason = disconnectCode And &hFF

   if (disconnectCode = &hB08 or majorDiscReason = 2 or majorDiscReason = 1) and not (extendedDiscReason = 5) then
      ReturnToConnectPage
      exit sub
   end if

   errMsgText = MsRdpClient.GetErrorDescription(disconnectCode, extendedDiscReason)
   if not errMsgText = "" then
         msgbox errMsgText,0,L_RemoteDesktopCaption_ErrorMessage
   end if

   ReturnToConnectPage

end sub
-->
</script>
```

The problem is, that only works in IE, still looking for Firefox / Safari... any luck??